# Coloring knot diagram obtained from colored one by applying crossing change to one crossing

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

Suppose $K_1$ is a knot diagram colored by a dihedral quandle $R_n$ of order $n$, By applying crossing change (exchanging over and under arcs) to one crossing in $K_1$, we obtain a new diagram let us say $K_2$. Then is it possible that $K_2$ is also colorable by the dihedral qaundle $R_n$ or it will be colored by a dihedral quandle of different cardinality

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that applying crossing change once may result in a very different knot. As an example, consider a knot with unknotting number $1$.